# Pointer to 2D array. Why does this example work?

Tags: c++, c

I have this code example, but I don't understand why changing the values in the array inside 
`outputUsingArray()` are changing the original array.

I would have expected changing the values of the array in `outputUsingArray()` would only be for a local copy of the array.

Why isn't that so?

However, this is the behaviour I would like, but I don't understand why it work.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void outputUsingArray(int array[][4], int n_rows, int n_cols) {
  int i, j;

  printf("Output Using array\n");
  for (i = 0; i < n_rows; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n_cols; j++) {
      // Either can be used.
      //printf("%2d ", array[i][j] );
      printf("%2d ", *(*(array+i)+j));
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n");

  array[0][0] = 100;
  array[2][3] = 200;

}

void outputUsingPointer(int (*array)[4], int n_rows, int n_cols) {
  int i, j;

  printf("Output Using Pointer to Array i.e. int (*array)[4]\n");
  for (i = 0; i < n_rows; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n_cols; j++) {
      printf("%2d ", *(*(array+i) + j ));
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main() {

  int array[3][4] = { { 0, 1, 2, 3 },
              { 4, 5, 6, 7 },
              { 8, 9, 10, 11 } };

  outputUsingPointer((int (*)[4])array, 3, 4);

  outputUsingArray(array, 3, 4);

  printf("0,0: %i\n", array[0][0]);
  printf("2,3: %i\n", array[2][3]);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

passing int[] is really passing the pointer to the first element of the array.
passing int* is passing the pointer to the first element of the array as well.

They're identical.

Since they're both pointing towards the same part of memory, changing one will change the other one.

Comment: and it works since array is a pointer to int[4] so it has a fixed size the compiler knows about so it can do index calculations

Comment: @Spudd86: No, this is not true. No index or bounds calculations are performed inside the function. The pointer to which the incoming array rvalue has decayed is simply incremented the required number of times -- this works because _int_ is known, not because the _4_ is known.

Comment: @Tomalak but `*(array + i)` wouldn't give the intended result if the compiler did not know about the 4 (ie it has to also be able to convert it into `(int *)array + i*4` otherwise the addressing would be wrong)

Comment: @Spudd86: Hang on, are you talking about `sizeof(int)` `4` (which comes from the type `int` and is thus not relevant), or the original array dimension `4` (which _does not exist inside the function_)? I don't really understand what you're saying.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm talking about the fact that if you write `int (*array)[4]` then `sizeof(*array) == sizeof(int) * 4` (ie: array is a pointer to an array of length 4, not a pointer to a pointer). The array dimension DOES exist inside the function because the declaration of the parameter specifies it.

Comment: @Spudd86: Oh, I get you. Yes, that's right: _all but the first_ dimension is known. Sorry, I had forgotten that this is a 2D array question.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C/C++ are not passed by value. i.e. there is NO copying involved when you pass an array as a parameter. i.e. `array` is just a name that references the passed array.

Comment: No, it references a pointer to which an rvalue to the array decayed.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C/C++ are really just pointers (with the math done for you).  Unless you explicitly make a copy of the contents of the array, passing an array is only passing a pointer to the first element.

So when you modify the array based on that base pointer, you're modifying the original array contents.

Comment: Arrays in C and C++ are not pointers.  They *decay* into pointers in *some* contexts, but they are not the same.

Comment: **Arrays are absolutely _not_ pointers**, any more than an `int` is.

Answer (score 0):

### Heading ##Hi The following is an example of creating a Two dimensional array and updating and then printing using **

```
#include&lt;stdio.h&gt;
#include&lt;stdlib.h&gt;

void showArray(double** theArray,int arraySizeX, int arraySizeY){
    int index,index2;

    for(index=0;index&lt;arraySizeX;index++){
        for(index2=0;index2&lt;arraySizeY;index2++){
            printf("The valyee of arr[%d][%d] is %lf  \n",index,index2,theArray[index][index2]);
        }
    }


}

void setArray(double** theArray,int arraySizeX, int arraySizeY){
    int index,index2;

    for(index=0;index&lt;arraySizeX;index++){
        for(index2=0;index2&lt;arraySizeY;index2++){
            theArray[index][index2]=index+index2;
        }
    }


}


void main()
{

    int i, arraySizeX =3,arraySizeY=4;


    double** theArray;
    theArray = (double**) malloc(arraySizeX*sizeof(double*));

    for ( i = 0; i &lt; arraySizeX; i++)  {
        theArray[i] = (double*) malloc(arraySizeY*sizeof(double));
    }


    printf("*****************************\n");
    showArray(theArray, arraySizeX,  arraySizeY);
    printf("*****************************\n");

    setArray(theArray, arraySizeX,  arraySizeY);

    printf("__________________________________\n");
    showArray(theArray, arraySizeX,  arraySizeY);
    printf("__________________________________\n");

    free(theArray);


}
```

I hope this helps,